# Spark 2.2.0:How to prevent CountVectorizer giving NoneZeroVector VectorsUDT from Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Hello, community i am a new member here and i would like to make a simple silly question. i am trying to convert text document in vectors with a given vocabulary. Just the same with the spark examples. My problem is that i take in some cases empty vectors.
It is very important to me to do something to handle it but i can't!!

Here is my code

```
 List<Row> data = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("zero", "zero", "zero")),
                RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")),
                RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b", "c", "a"))
        );
        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                new StructField("text", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, true), false, Metadata.empty())
        });
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema);


         // alternatively, define CountVectorizerModel with a-priori vocabulary
        CountVectorizerModel cvm = new CountVectorizerModel(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"})
                .setInputCol("text")
                .setOutputCol("feature");

        cvm.transform(df).show(false);
```

Here is the Output. i would like to handle or delete the first column or is any other option to instantiate empty vectors to 0.0

```
+------------------+-------------------------+
|text              |feature                  |
+------------------+-------------------------+
|[zero, zero, zero]|(3,[],[])                |
|[a, b, c]         |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|[a, b, b, c, a]   |(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
+------------------+-------------------------+
```

i would appreciate if someone could help me do it in java

Comment: Why would you consider that? Lack of presence of a value (`(3,[],[])` is the same as saying that input doesn't contain "a", "b" or "c") is a valuable information (pun intended).

Comment: because this is a minimal ecample in my case i have  large text and it is important to me to handle this in order to continue.In my large text i got 3% empty vectors  in 1000 words. i want to prevent this because i am not able to use othe methods like MinhashLSH for example

Answer (score 1):

To

> instantiate empty vectors to 0.0

You don't have to do anything. `(3,[],[])` is not empty - it is  a `SparseVector` representation equivalent to `DenseVector` `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`.

**To delete**:

You can create an `udf`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector;

UDF1 isEmpty = new UDF1<Vector,Boolean>() {
    public Boolean call(Vector vector) throws Exception {
        return vector.toSparse().numActives() == 0;
    }
};

spark.udf().register("isEmpty", isEmpty, DataTypes.BooleanType);
```

and use it with `SQLTransformer`:

```
SQLTransformer sqlTrans = new SQLTransformer().setStatement(
  "SELECT * FROM __THIS__ WHERE NOT isEmpty(feature)");
```

but please don't - "empty" vector is a source of valuable information.